# Asp Core, How to use PagingList<T>.CreateAsync() with a viewModel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sorting, asp.net-core, paging

I am working on a asp.net core 1.1 project and i want to create paging in my some views. I studied microsoft documents about paging in asp core but it is very simple mode with 1 table. In my view i use multi table and use a `viewmodel` to initialize it. I want to use `PagingList<T>.CreateAsync()` method to create paging but get error:
`can not convert from system.linq.Iqueryable<> to system.linq.IorderedQueryable<>`

**my action:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? page)
    {
        List<BookListViewModel> model = new List<BookListViewModel>();
        var query = (from b in _context.books
                     join a in _context.authors on b.AuthorID equals a.AuthorId
                     join bg in _context.bookgroups on b.BookGroupID equals bg.BookGroupId


                     select new
                     {
                         b.BookId,
                         b.BookName,
                         b.BookPageCount,
                         b.BookImage,
                         b.AuthorID,
                         b.BookGroupID,
                         a.AuthorName,
                         bg.BookGroupName
                     });

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            BookListViewModel objmodel = new BookListViewModel();

            objmodel.BookId = item.BookId;
            objmodel.BookName = item.BookName;
            objmodel.BookImage = item.BookImage;
            objmodel.BookPageCount = item.BookPageCount;
            objmodel.AuthorId = item.AuthorID;
            objmodel.BookGroupId = item.BookGroupID;
            objmodel.AuthorName = item.AuthorName;
            objmodel.BookGroupName = item.BookGroupName;

            model.Add(objmodel);

        }
        ViewBag.RootPath = "/upload/thumbnailimage/";
        int pageSize = 3;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        return View(await PagingList<BookListViewModel>.CreateAsync(model.AsQueryable() , pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

I have not yet written anything about paging in `index` view and it is a simple list of viewmodel

Comment: there is no idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well can't really be sure from the code you posted. But the exception says the the `CreateAsync` method needs `IOrderedQueryable`, but you're giving it an `IQueryable`.

Try changing it to pass in the `query` object (which I guess should implement the `IOrderedQueryable`, if you're using Entity framework).

The idea behind the `PagingList` (presumably) is to use it to do the paging in the database.
What you're doing is bringing the filterted set into memory (when for-eaching through the result), and then doing doing the paging.

The code might look something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
{
  var query = (from b in _context.books
               join a in _context.authors on b.AuthorID equals a.AuthorId
               join bg in _context.bookgroups on b.BookGroupID equals bg.BookGroupId


               select new BookListViewModel()
               {
                 BookId = b.BookId,
                 BookName = b.BookName,
                 BookPageCount = b.BookPageCount,
                 BookImage = b.BookImage,
                 AuthorId = b.AuthorID,
                 BookGroupId = b.BookGroupID,
                 AuthorName = a.AuthorName,
                 BookGroupName = bg.BookGroupName
               }).AsNoTracking().OrderBy(u => u.BookId);


  ViewBag.RootPath = "/upload/thumbnailimage/";

  var pagedResult = await PagingList<BookListViewModel>.CreateAsync(query, 10, page);
  return View(pagedResult);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I change it to `IOrderedQueryable` There is also an error. I asked another question on this subject here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354813/asp-core-how-to-create-paging)

Comment: I added some example code. Does that help? If not, try posting your `PagingList` class.