# Asp Core, How to create Paging?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, paging

I want to use `PagingList<T>.CreateAsync()` to create PagedList in index view but get below error in line `var modelPaging = await PagingList<UserListViewModel>.CreateAsync(model, 10, page);`:

> can not convert from system.collection.Generic.List<> to system.linq.IorderedQueryable<>

**my action code :**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
    {

        List<UserListViewModel> model = new List<UserListViewModel>();
        model = _userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().Select(u => new UserListViewModel
        {
            Id = u.Id,
            FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
            Email = u.Email
        }).OrderBy(u => u.Id).ToList();
        var modelPaging = await PagingList<UserListViewModel>.CreateAsync(model, 10, page);

        return View(modelPaging);
    }
```

**and UserListViewModel Viewmodel:**

```
public class UserListViewModel
{

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }

}
```

What changes should I make  in my code?

I asked another question on this subject here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48350710/asp-core-how-to-use-paginglistt-createasync-with-a-viewmodel/48354828#48354828)

Comment: I assume that `OrderBy(u => u.Id)` returns an `IOrderedQueryable`. Thus, you can remove `ToList()`. If it doesn't, then add `AsQueryable().OrderBy(u => u.Id)` instead of `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear that tells you `CreateAsync` needs `IOrderedQueryable` but you are giving the data already retrieved from database. You should pass the query itself. Remove `ToList`;

```
var query = _userManager.Users.AsNoTracking().Select(u => new UserListViewModel
{
    Id = u.Id,
    FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,
    Email = u.Email
}).OrderBy(u => u.Id);
var modelPaging = await PagingList<UserListViewModel>.CreateAsync(query, 10, page);
```

The main purpose of `PagingList` apply the pagination directly from database instead of in-memory.